# NullPointerException Exception when trying to get the value of a field in an Entity in Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I have a Student Entity which has a field in it which is a reference to a Department Entity like this.
         `@Load  private @Index Ref<Department> department;`
   Then the getter and setter for the Department field is shown below

```
 public Department getDepartment() {
    return department.get();
}

public void setDepartment(Key<Department> department) {
    this.department = Ref.create(department);
}
```

The Student Entity also has a field in it which holds a reference to a SchoolFaculty Entity

```
@Load
private @Index Ref<SchoolFaculty> schoolFaculty;
```

It has the following getter and setter

```
  public SchoolFaculty getSchoolFaculty() {
      if (schoolFaculty != null) 
           return schoolFaculty.get();
 return null;     
}

public void setSchoolFaculty(Key<SchoolFaculty> schoolFaculty) { 
    this.schoolFaculty = Ref.create(schoolFaculty); 
}
```

The Department Entity in turn has a field in it which holds a key to a Faculty Entity as shown below

```
@Index
private Key<SchoolFaculty> schoolFaculty;
```

the getter and setter for the field is shown below

```
 public String getSchoolFaculty() {
    return schoolFaculty.toWebSafeString();
}


public void setSchoolFaculty(Key<SchoolFaculty> schoolFaculty) {
    this.schoolFaculty = schoolFaculty;
}
```

I have created a Department and SchoolFaculty Entity in the Local  datastore using the google Api Explorer, the Department has its SchoolFaculty reference set to a valid value which is also present in the SchoolFaculty table, that is the Department has a faculty, but when I try to set the SchoolFaculty of a student using the following code I get a NullPointerException. Here is the code

```
 student.setDepartment(Key.create(Department.class,student_programme.getDepartmentRef()));// student_programme is a reference to an Entity which I use to get the department and it works fine and the student gets its Department set to the Department Value.
        if(student.getDepartment().getSchoolFaculty()) != null){     student.setSchoolFaculty(Key.create(SchoolFaculty.class,getDepartment().getSchoolFaculty()));}// this  is the line throws a null pointer Exception
```

I am using objectify for the datastore transaction and all reference to the objectify dependencies have been added.

Comment: because the `student.getDepartment().getSchoolFaculty()` is throwing null pointer before the condition statement is triggered, and google appengine key can not create a key for null entity or websafestring

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because the `student.getDepartment().getSchoolFaculty()` is throwing null pointer before the condition statement is triggered, and google appengine key can not create a key for null entity or websafestring. So carefully debug and check if the `getDepartment()` is returning null or what it returns first, and if you want to create a null field of a key with data store using Key is to use the **default** e.g

```
Key.create(SchoolFaculty.class, "default"); // when it is null
```

hope this is useful

Comment: getDepartment() was returning a web safe string and not the Department entity.